# How to use Telerik RadChart in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using RadChart in asp.net web page and it shows error

```
The Chart http handler is not registered. Please, manually add the following line to your Web.config httpHandlers section:
```

when I use these line in webConfig file then its shows in browser
[image]

How remove that error.
If anyone has an idea please share with me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

This error 500.23 translates to - An ASP.NET httpHandlers configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.

Check the httpHandlers configuration in IIS. Try following:

1. Open Server Manager
2. Select Roles>Web Server (IIS)>IIS Manager>Select the Server>Applocation Pools
3. Select the appPool that your asp.net app is running under>Click on 'Advanced Settings' from the right hand pane.
4. Under Advanced Settings>General>Managed Pipeline Mode, select "Classic"
5. Recycle app pool and test your app.